# How to deploy solidity smart contract on IOTA ? i appreciate any tutorial or document suggestion!

Tags: iota-network, smart-contract, hornet, wasp, solidity

i started by running a hornet-nest-node and wasp node on devnet , then i installed wasp-cli to interact with my node but i didn't figure out what are next steps !
my wasp-config.json :

```
{
  "database": {
    "directory": "/wasp/waspdb"
  },
  "inx": {
    "address": "hornet-nest:9029",
    "maxConnectionAttempts": 30
  },
  "logger": {
    "level": "debug",
    "disableCaller": false,
    "disableStacktrace": true,
    "encoding": "console",
    "outputPaths": [
      "stdout",
      "wasp.log"
    ],
    "disableEvents": true
  },
  "network": {
    "bindAddress": "0.0.0.0",
    "externalAddress": "auto"
  },
  "node": {
    "disablePlugins": [],
    "enablePlugins": []
  },
  "users": {
    "wasp": {
      "password": "wasp",
      "permissions": [
        "dashboard",
        "api",
        "chain.read",
        "chain.write"
      ]
    }
  },
  "webapi": {
    "auth": {
      "jwt": {
        "durationHours": 24
      },
      "basic": {
        "username": "wasp"
      },
      "ip": {
        "whitelist": [
          "127.0.0.1"
        ]
      },
      "scheme": "none"
    },
    "bindAddress": "0.0.0.0:9090"
  },
  "dashboard": {
    "auth": {
      "jwt": {
        "durationHours": 24
      },
      "basic": {
        "username": "wasp"
      },
      "ip": {
        "whitelist": [
          "127.0.0.1"
        ]
      },
      "scheme": "basic"
    },
    "bindAddress": "0.0.0.0:7000"
  },
  "peering": {
    "port": 4000,
    "netid": "0.0.0.0:4000"
  },
  "nanomsg": {
    "port": 5550
  },
  "metrics": {
    "bindAddress": "0.0.0.0:2112",
    "enabled": true
  }
}
```

i appreciate any suggestion if there is onother way or tutorial !

Answer (score 1):

You don't need your infra to deploy a smart contract you can also just deploy it to the [testnet EVM](https://wiki.iota.org/build/networks-endpoints/#testnet-evm). And what do you mean with devnet? Hornet-nest runs a standalone private network. Are you using the local_setup of wasp?
But as I said I would not recommend starting with your own chain. Use our public infra, then everything is pretty similar to deploying any standard EVM contract. For [example](https://wiki.iota.org/wasp-evm/how-tos/ERC20/).

Comment: Thank you for responding. As a newcomer to IOTA, I'm in the exploration phase and aiming to build a basic Dapp within a local IOTA network, incorporating a Solidity smart contract similar to how it's done on Ethereum's blockchain. While I'm aware that the functioning isn't identical, I'm eager to comprehend the process. I've attempted to set up a local Wasp node following a tutorial [link](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-deploy-smart-contracts-iota/) , but encountered difficulties getting it to run properly...and ok thank you for your recommandation i will start by using public infrastructure .